# Can we acknowledge a range of entries (or entries older than a certain id) in Redis streams?

Tags: redis, redis-streams

Is it possible to acknowledge multiple entries in a redis stream based on a range of IDs? I am specifically interested in acknowledging everything before a certain ID, instead of acknowledging one by one.

Or alternatively, is it possible to only read entries with IDs bigger than the last acknowledged ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to `XACK` a range of IDs built in command. Technically it can be done using Lua script.

As for the second part of your question see the [XREADGROUP](https://redis.io/commands/xreadgroup) docs.

```
The special > ID, which means that the consumer want to receive only messages that were never delivered to any other consumer. It just means, give me new messages.
```

Comment: The > ID sends the messages that have not been delivered yet, while I'm interested in getting the messages after the last acknowledged ID, which may or may not be already delivered.

Comment: For that you'll have to also call xpending